# How to get/use User access token for Facebook Open Graph (as a cron job)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I use following code with Facebook PHP-SDK to access a page feed:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'yyyyy',
));

$feed = $facebook->api("/page_id/posts");
```

It works fine. The code is used in a cron job in the web server to retrieve page feeds automatically and periodically, therefore there is no user interaction to log in or log out.

If I print the access code by $facebook->getAccessToken(), I can see the access code is actually a "App access token". (Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ , there are four kinds of access tokens)

What if I want to use a "User access token" instead in such a cron job (no physical user to login), how to do it? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Extending the user's access token**

You can exchange the user's access token with the `long-lived` access token (2-months) validity. Go though the link to get the long-lived token. But then you have to refresh the token after 60 days by the same login process.

[Extending tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

**Extending the page's access token**

As an alternative, you can have a `never` expiring token for your fan page, that will solve your problem too I guess. To get this token-

Make the following call using the long-lived user's access token -

```
    $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
```

(You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token)